# how to generate a random string + text + multiple lines

Tags: php, string, random

I actually got this script from here... but it is not quite what I needed...

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

// Echo the random string.
// Optionally, you can give it a desired string length.
<?php echo generateRandomString(); ?>
?>
```

basically, I wanted this small php script to generate thousands of lines (~3000)...

in this format:

```
mytext/(the_random_string_here)
mytext/(the_random_string_here)
mytext/(the_random_string_here)
mytext/(the_random_string_here)
mytext/(the_random_string_here)
```

up to the very end (~3000 lines) with each line have a random string...

Comment: You should remove the characters 0 and 1 (zero and one) and l, (lowercase L) O and L as these characters can easily be confused with each other.

Comment: personally I prefer str_shuffle, http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php for random strings that and substr, it's several times faster then a loop.

Comment: You need to learn about **loops**. They are one of the most essential parts of programming. In this case use a **for** loop, though a while loop would work too. Read here about loops in PHP: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_loop_types.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a **for** loop to generate it 3000 times

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3000; $i++){
    echo 'mytext/'.generateRandomString().'<br>';
}
```

The answer was inside your code snippet that you provided

Answer (score 0):

If the number of lines is known, a `for` loop is a good choice. There is a nice example of such a loop right there in the `generateRandomString` function.

You could do something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3000; $i++) {
   echo "mytext/(" . generateRandomString() . ")<br>\n";
}
```