# How to create a php script that echo'es from txt document

Tags: php

I am not really a coder... and I have search around about this small script...

However, I only found a script that will echo the entire content of a file and not by line.

Can you guys help me write a small script that will echo or print out

a random line from a text file (by url - www.mydomain.com/myfile.txt)

the myfile.txt will have thousands of lines
ie:

```
random-text here 1
random-text here 2
random-text here 3
random-text here 4
random-text here 5
```

I only want to randomly echo a line... for example:
only echo

> random-text here 4

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify this PHP script please: generate random string + text + multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151782/modify-this-php-script-please-generate-random-string-text-multiple-lines)

Comment: that's a repost of yours btw ^

Comment: it is not a duplicate... it is an additional/extra function that i wanted

Comment: well I don't see a green tick next to that answer give. This site goes both ways.

Comment: Hey Fred... I am not following what you are trying to say... i am quite new to stackoverflow.. what do you mean by green tick?

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to Stack ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), i.e..

```
$lines = file('yourfile.txt');
echo $lines[4];
```

if you want to echo a random line, use `rand`, i.e.:

```
$lines = file('yourfile.txt');
echo $lines[rand(0, count($lines)) -1];
```

---

[file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

> file — Reads entire file into an array

Comment: Hi Pedro, I went to http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php and tried the example... edited the $lines and echo to your suggestions... but it throws up an error... 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' in /home/****

Comment: my bad, 1 parenthesis missing, corrected now !

Comment: Thanks! it seems to work as I wanted... however... when I refresh the browser... 
"SOMETIMES" 
it also gives out a blank or does not echo anything...
I would like it to echo any text from the line and not blank

Comment: I just tried the code again on phpfiddle and got this error:

E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined offset: -1 -- at line 3

Comment: Try it on a real server, it will work.